# Input List - Double/Triple Digits

Tags: list, python-3.x, numbers, digits

I was wondering how I would get my code to detect double digits or triple digits and put them into the list. Currently it separates any double digits and assigns a list value for each digit instead of each number. For example if the user enters "5 55 6 45 3", the programs enters it as ["5","5","5","6","4","5","3"].Thank you.

```
main_list = list(input("Enter numbers: "))
for vals in main_list:
    if vals == " ":
        main_list.remove(vals)
print("The original numbers are",main_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.split()` method for strings (working with the string directly, not `list(...)`): `input("Enter numbers: ").split(' ')` returns

```
["5", "55", "6", "45", "3"]
```

i.e. it splits the string at each `' '`. Be careful of what happens if there is a double space: You will get empty strings in the list. So the best way to go is probably to check if the string is non-empty:

```
[x for x in input("Enter numbers: ").split(' ') if x]
```

Note also that this works in Python3.x only (because the return value of `input` is a string). The corresponding function for Python 2 is `raw_input()`. So if you need to make it compatible with both you could use

```
try:
    [x for x in raw_input("Enter numbers: ").split(' ') if x]
except NameError:
    [x for x in input("Enter numbers: ").split(' ') if x]
```

but not the other way around (`input()` exists in Python2, it just does't do the same thing).